# How to show camera options (e.g. zoom) when opening the camera within an app on a Nokia X10 with Android 12

Tags: android, nokia, android-12

My app has a feature where you can take pictures. On a Nokia X10 with Android 12 when the camera is opened from within the app, camera options (e.g. zoom) aren't shown. On any other devices I have tested with Android 12, the camera options are shown.

The camera is being opened like this:

`Activity a = getActivity(); Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); a.startActivityForResult(intent, 10);`

I installed a random camera app from the Play Store on the same Nokia X10. Here the camera options are shown. Is there a another way for how to open the camera, e.g. with specific settings or flags?

Comment: `a another way for how to open the camera?` The camera? Or the options?

Comment: "On any other devices I have tested with Android 12, the camera options are shown" -- the behavior of a camera app is up to the developers of the camera app, not you or me. There are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps and many more available for installation from the Play Store. None have to have the concept of "camera options". "Is there a another way for how to open the camera?" -- if you do not need the resulting image, [you can try `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en#intent_action_still_image_camera)

Comment: @CommonsWare For the other app I installed from the Play Store, which has a camera feature, the camera options are shown. That's why I assumed - since for another app on the same device the camera options are shown - I must call the camera differently to bring up the camera options.